# Resteasy @path with zero or more path parameters

Tags: java, url, resteasy

I am using RESTEasy in my API development. My url is `http://localhost:8080/project/player/M` or `http://localhost:8080/project/player`

it means am pasing {gender} as path param.

my problem is how to mapp this url to REST method, i use below mapping

```
@GET
@Path("player/{gender}")
@Produces("application/json")
```

but if use it, it maps for `http://localhost:8080/project/player/M` but not for `http://localhost:8080/project/player`. 
i need a regular expression to map zero or more path parameters

Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Path parameters (`@PathParam`) aren't optional. If you want to map;

- http://localhost:8080/project/player/M
- http://localhost:8080/project/player

You will need two methods. You can use method overloading;

```
@GET
@Path("player/{gender}")
@Produces("application/json")
public Whatever myMethod(@PathParam("gender") final String gender) {
  // your implementation here
}

@GET
@Path("player")
@Produces("application/json")
public Whatever myMethod() {
  return myMethod(null);
}
```

Comment: I don't think this is correct.  See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5421104/optional-pathparam-in-jax-rs

Answer (score 10):

Is there any reason this must be a path parameter and not a query string ?  If you change it to use the latter, then you can use a @DefaultValue annotation.

So your code would then look like the following:

```
@GET
@Path("player") //example: "/player?gender=F"
@Produces("application/json")
public Whatever myMethod(@QueryParam("gender") @DefaultValue("M") final String gender) {
  // your implementation here
}
```

Comment: Even though this is not a direct answer to the question it is the right thing to do. REST paths shouldn't have optional parts. I was doing this wrong and this answer "woke me up".

Answer (score 1):

See the below link which has a sample of optional path parameters via regular expressions

[RestEasy @Path Question with regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4071008/resteasy-path-question-with-regular-expression)

Comment: I would not recommend you to use regular expressions as path parameters. It just complicates a relatively simple problem...

Answer (score 0):

You should use regex when you want have optional parameter in path.

So your code would then look like the following:

```
@GET
@Path("/player{gender : (/\\w+)?}")
@Produces("application/json;charset=UTF-8")
public Whatever myMethod(@QueryParam("gender") @DefaultValue("M") final String gender) {
  // your implementation here
}
```

For more information see https://docs.jboss.org/resteasy/docs/1.1.GA/userguide/html/Using__Path_and__GET___POST__etc..html